# TSV file column removal?

Tags: csv, text, cmd

Is it possible to remove TSV file columns without opening the file in excel? and can it read an external file where all the removed column name is listed? if so how do you do it in windows 8 from a command prompt?

Comment: Without excel, sure. In windows? How comfortable are you with powershell?

Comment: Nope powershell is not an option. Can't install in a corporate environment- has to be using available CMD option.

Comment: You may want to check out something like this http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: Is using Windows Script Host (wsh) an Option?

Comment: @cricket_007 I'd also support the approach at the site you mentioned. If it has to be "pure" batch file, this is the way to go.